# Answer appears automatically converted as a comment

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, convert-to-comment, link-only-answers, answers-as-comments

I posted an answer (pointing to another question already asked) but when I hit submit, I saw my answer appear as a comment to the question instead.

I tried it a couple of times and still the same result. The answer gets eaten up and is transformed into a comment.

Is this a bug?

Comment: It's a bug in the Stack Overflow developers.

Comment: It's a bug in the answerer.

Comment: @paulmorriss: [It absolutely is _not_.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98950/answer-appears-automatically-converted-as-a-comment/99096#99096)

Comment: You can do this using [this workaround](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298385/364527).

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Trivial answers containing a link to another question in the network are automatically converted to comments on the question, with the message

> Trivial answer converted to comment

Poking some folks about perhaps a wee bit more indication that that happens, looked like a bug to me at first too.

---

**23 Mar 2023**: We updated the warning message for the poster so they are more likely to realize what happened to their answer when it got converted to a comment by the system. This links to the [deleted answers help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers), which we'll be updating with a brief explanation of what happens when an answer is converted to a comment.

[image: Toast notice with the text "Your answer has been automatically converted to a comment. Learn more"]

Comment: I would say that if it confuses those who know about it, it's probably not good UI design :)

Comment: @dan well, we really want these users who post "answers" that are short links to other SE, Inc questions to ... stop ... so it's either do this, or have your "answer" downvoted and/or deleted.

Comment: @Daniel - I didn't actually know about it.  I agree its confusing, tweaking that a bit if I can.

Comment: I've updated the [list of current automatic content modifications](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97524/list-of-reasons-for-automatic-system-content-modification) to include this.

Comment: @Kevin - perhaps unrelated, but there was a similar change requested: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83912/autoconvert-site-internal-link-only-answers-to-comments

Comment: @Jeff apologies, what would be helpful is to display a message at the top explaining what's happened, and a link to a faq page explaining similar behaviour and desired usage. I know I for one would be too lazy to read it until I do something that I get notified is undesired.

Comment: @Jeff, Is this something which could be relaxed on Meta?  I understand the utility on Stack Overflow, etc, but here -- when users ask if something is off-topic, for example -- I have thought a one sentence explanation and a link to a similar question would suffice??

Comment: This is poor. With 91k rep on SO I'm sure I've got the hang of *answering* questions...

Comment: @Jeff can you explain why you dont want short answers (I take it this is what is meant by trivial) that link to an answer to another question. This is why I want the faq because I'm relatively new and don't understand this. I've tried searching meta and found one understandable reason mentioned here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17447 for answers like "why don't you post it over here" but is that really common? The most common reason I would have thought is linking to an answer that answers the question which this meta question says is ok http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21270

Comment: @Jeff if this behaviour was mainly intended for "why don't you post it over here" or "I think your question is similar to" then why not exclude links to answers from this behaviour so that only answers with links to questions or faq pages etc are automatically converted to a comment.

Comment: Can we do this for all answers where the link is more than 10% of the total answer length, for any link (not just internal links)? A link is not an answer - it's a pointer to an answer, perhaps, but not an answer.

Comment: In that case, is it a bug if it leaves the [link][1] stuff in, which doesn't get interpreted properly in the comments field?

Comment: @JeffAtwood, can you post that as an answer so I can downvote you? Sometimes the answer is just short.

Comment: @JeffAtwood I just had this happen to me for the first time and it puzzled me; after I pressed submit my answer text was still in the the answer box so it triggered me to submit again until I noticed I had now 2 identical comments, which I removed and then again. The algorithm was right about my post, but the feedback made it seem like a bug.

Comment: I find it amusing that even if I am unable to comment on a question I can answer trivially, and thus still comment. An oversight if you ask me.

Comment: In my opinion this is an awesome feature on paper, but I find it to be absolutely annoying. There is a point where people are just going to get frustrated by the level of hand holding that's going on. Please don't put us in the position where we are actually considering using the asp.net forums instead...

Comment: @JeffAtwood What happened to letting the community decide whether an answer was good enough to be one or not? Now you're allowing Skynet to make that decision and it fails just like it did in Terminator.

Comment: @Nick While [I'm also frustrated by the feature](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/q/1695/1672), the community is *really* bad at voting on things like this. People definitely upvote trivial answers. People upvote answers that *are explicitly copies of answers from other questions*. And even high-rep users sometimes post things that are too trivial. The one time I ran into this, I realized I was indeed doing a bad job of summarizing what I was linking to. It's just the implementation that's problematic.

Comment: So, actually, users having less than 50 rep **can** comment, but they must post an aswer with a link and their comment is very short. I think it should be placed in FAQ under 'How can I make comments having less than 50 rep'.

Comment: This is still in place, and is still very annoying, and very wrong. Answer-like posts should not be in the comments section, ever, so in what situations is this desirable?

Comment: Why does it only do that for answers with links to another question in the network and not for all link-only answers?

Answer (score 156):

This feature is really undesirable. Some questions may be answered perfectly well in a couple of sentences.

"[`var` is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206105/what-does-php-keyword-var-do), and you forgot the `$` in `$idgen`" is perfectly acceptable as an answer, especially when I *explicitly* didn't want to just throw the full completed code snippet at the OP.

It doesn't help that the conversion kept the answer-style decoupled link syntax, which comment Markdown doesn't support; thus my post was (a) completely mangled, (b) not posted where I wanted it to be posted, and (c) not posted where it *belonged*.

At 28.5k rep, I know what an answer looks like and what a comment looks like. Stop second guessing me!

Comment: The problem was that you were linking to another Stack Overflow question. If you'd linked to the original source then it might have OK.

Comment: I'm with you. It needs weighted for, say, user rep

Comment: Just to add - if you're linking to another Stack Overflow question, maybe you should be voting to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @ChrisF: No. You should vote to close as a duplicate when the question is a duplicate; no other time. That's why it's called "closing as a duplicate".

Comment: I did say *maybe* - I agree it's not always the case, but it's usually a good indication.

Comment: @ChrisF: In fact, 100% of the time when I'm linking to another SO question, it's not a duplicate. Because if it's a duplicate, I vote to close as such. :)

Comment: bah, this kinda sucks ... my "answer" is in fact to point them to the other SO answer which answered it much better. Now it can't be chosen as the answer to the question - this will only suggest people that they should copy/paste the other answer.

Comment: In this case, the other answer didn't answer the question at hand. "You need a linker" was the answer. The link was for additional information -- essentially, answering the OP's _next_ question.

Comment: I'm with you. This is incredibly annoying and disgustingly paternalistic. I'm going to avoid contributing to stackoverflow in the future since it evidently already knows the answers better than I do.

Comment: StackOverflow got mad at you for the stuff between the `<!--` and `-->`.

Comment: @muntoo: No, I added that on my third attempt.

Comment: Can't agree more, I'm tired of SO second-guessing me and insulting my intelligence...

Comment: I think the point is to get more self-contained answers, not just links to other questions. You may, for example, copy the relevant parts of the page you are linking to.

Comment: I second that. Having a simplistic computer algorhitm somewhere decide whether my answer should be an answer or a comment is a bit too much for me to take. I thought SO was a community driven site. Why bother... why don't you let the computer answer itself, since it's that smart? Maybe I don't have time to write a detailed answer and spoon feeding it to the OP, does that make me un-worthy of answering? Fine... maybe someone else has more time for that. Why bother.

Comment: @Catfish: To be fair, "I found how to get all of the results from this answer stackoverflow.com/questions/14829130/…" is _not_ an answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I disagree. I could either point to someone's answer, or copy and paste his answer into my question, which is stealing. If i quote where my answer came from, the user that answered the original quesion will not the the rep. I can totally see myself coming across that exact same problem in the future and googling it and coming across my question and looking for the answer. Since the answer got converted to a comment, its' not apparent that is how I solved it previously.

Comment: @Catfish: Links are not answers, and that's been done to death on Meta already. If your question turned out to be the same as some other question, vote to close it as a duplicate. If an answer to a marginally-related question helped, link to it but also quote enough information so that it makes sense on _your_ question. Show the final code. Don't just write "I got my answer _here_" as that is not an answer but a blog entry. :)

Comment: See [my answer below](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298385/364527) for a workaround.

Comment: @Alex: I thought I'd tried that before and it had not worked

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Maybe something changed? I added in a link to an example of it working in the answer.

Comment: @Alex: Yeah I'm saying it must have changed

Comment: [v] stupid site. (checked)

Comment: "At 28.5k rep"... don't you mean 306.6k rep? ;-)

Comment: @ShaWiz How times have changed! (not really)

Comment: We need to stop closing questions as duplicates because they turn out to have the same answer: they are still different questions!

Answer (score 22):

This is terrible. If it's another question *on the same site*, then I get it- it's a duplicate, effectively. But if the question is *on a different site*, then it's not a duplicate and the questioner could not have found it by searching the site he was on.

Come on guys, this is definitively unnecessary.

Comment: It's still a trivial answer, regardless of whether it's a viable duplicate.  If you're going to answer a question, answer it with a real answer - not just a link.

Comment: @jadarnel27: It was a real answer. That answer happened to be both short and contain a link to another question. But it was still an answer.

Comment: Here's the [answer that's typically link to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) concerning link-only answers.  The most important bit (I think) is this: "*...the question "answer" should actually contain an answer. Not just a bunch of directions towards the answer.*"

Comment: @jadarnel27: It was a perfectly good answer. The link just happened to add more content.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't trying to say your specific answer wasn't helpful, or even correct.  It's just not a good answer answer *for Stack Exchange* - because it makes people chase the answer (through the link) and it's quite possible that it won't be useful to future visitors (due to link rot).

Comment: @JoshDarnell are you suggesting we should duplicate answers when they are relevant to a different question?

Answer (score 13):

Post your answer without the link; then edit in the link.

For example post this answer:

> According to the dev lead at company X this is not currently possible.

Then edit the answer to this:

> According to the dev lead at company X [this is not currently possible](https://stackoverflow.com/link-to-relevant-post).

[Linked example of this working.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44785398/getting-python-cloud-endpoint-enum-values-on-an-android-client/45087242#45087242)

Answer (score 2):

I didn't notice the conversion, and posted the same link three times, and now I can't delete those comments because of lack of reputation. Sorry to say, but that's quite absurd. At least there should be a proper notification for what happened.

Comment: I know it's not ideal but as the [accepted answer above](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98955/348196) states, when your answer is automatically converted to a comment, three things happen: 1) You're redirected to the comment (via an anchor link). 2) The comment is highlighted. 3) A one-time message is shown below the comment telling you what happened ([like this](https://i.imgur.com/rFyHDCN.png)).

Comment: That said, I suppose you're referring to your comments under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32653394/8967612) (right?) I just flagged the two extra ones as no longer needed. They should be deleted soon.

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to that question. That was quick, thanks. I didn't see any redirection, I believe. I could be wrong, I was just baffled about what happened... and not just once.

Comment: You might be interested in [this feature request asking for <50 rep users to be allowed to delete their own auto-generated comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351079/allow-low-reputation-users-to-delete-comments-that-were-posted-on-their-behalf). I've edited your case in so its argument for implementation is stronger.