# Why was my apparently "trivial answer" converted to a comment?

Tags: support, comments, answers

I posted an answer, but it got converted to comment with a note saying

> Trivial answer converted to comment.

Why did that happen?

Comment: Do you have a link to the answer/comment?

Comment: Was it a link-only answer? They get converted to a comment automatically. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107063/how-could-a-user-with-1-reputation-point-leave-a-comment/107064#107064 and also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98950/answer-appears-automatically-converted-as-a-comment

Comment: Was it this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441245/add-delay-in-between-two-if-conditions#comment23580665_16441245

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441245/add-delay-in-between-two-if-conditions#comment23580665_16441245 this is the link

Comment: we want a fat juicy answer with your effort  in it!

Comment: It seems that a computer algorithm is deciding whether your answer is trival, and whether you've put enough effort in it!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you mean [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16438088/how-do-i-add-prev-and-next-buttons-to-my-jquery-slider#comment23576110_16438088) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441245/add-delay-in-between-two-if-conditions#comment23580665_16441245) comment it is probably because you are providing link only answers which get converted to comment automatically.

Comment: This is it. You can't just chuck in a link saying `"here's the answer" now give me reps.`

Comment: @tombull89 since when? this is outrageous. I expect free rep for copy & paste.