# Misclick with duplicate flag, now unable to delete automatic comment as I never had the rep to comment in the first place -- is this intended?

Tags: support, comments, duplicate-questions

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68664729/how-to-show-animation-when-event-click-is-process-without-stopping-animation-in#comment121597286_68664729), I accidentally marked it as a duplicate of the wrong link. I retracted the flag, no harm done. But my comment remains and I cannot delete it, and I figure this is because I don't have the rep to make comments anyway. Is this intended? How do I delete that comment?

edit: I cannot flag the comment either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allow low-reputation users to delete comments that were posted on their behalf](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351079/allow-low-reputation-users-to-delete-comments-that-were-posted-on-their-behalf)

Comment: You should flag it and ask for a moderator's help to delete it.

Comment: A better duplicate: [<50 reputation users can't delete comments that were posted on their behalf](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313474/571958)