# Should I flag a comment if it is posted by someone who has only 1 rep?

Tags: support, comments, flags, comment-flags, convert-to-comment

In order to post comments a user must first earn at least 50 rep

> [Users with at least 50 reputation may comment on any post.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) (There is no reputation requirement to post comments on MSO only; doing so elsewhere, including on other meta sites, requires 50 reputation.)

On EL&U I have on two or three occasions noted when a comment has been posted by a user who has only 1 rep. In light of the rules stated above, I have always thought it best to flag this anomaly. However, on a different SE site, when I flagged a comment accompanied with this message, “***how can a user with only 1 rep post a comment?***” my flag was **declined**, and the comment was allowed to remain. The comment I flagged [did not contain a link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107064/223820), it was not offensive, vulgar or inappropriate in any way, but it was posted by someone who precisely had 1 rep. The new user is unregistered, and has been a member of this particular SE site for two days.

What should I do the next time I see this happening? Ignore it, if it is inoffensive and not spammy. Or still flag the comment with an appropriate message?

### Conclusion

Thanks to @Nathan Tuggy and @nicael's answers, it appears that the comment made by a user with 1 rep was in all likelihood a low-quality answer that had been converted into a comment by a mod. On that particular site, I have less than 10K rep, so I cannot see deleted answers. However, couldn't the mod who declined my flag, expanded on the response? I realize it's a bit tiresome, but I would have at least "known" why the flag had been declined.

Comment: @rene no this wasn't written by the op, and the post is two years old too.  There were no links either on the comment. It's still there. The user still has 1 rep. The OP posted the question in 2013, and his rep is clearly visible. The OP is also active

Comment: tough crowd this lot, three downvotes and counting.

Comment: +1 - As I have also seen this, and wondered how and why... Nathan's [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272199/should-i-flag-a-comment-if-it-is-posted-by-someone-who-has-only-1-rep#answer-272202) provides the answers that I was looking for.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A comment left by a <50-rep user came about in one of four ways:

1. They used to have enough rep, but now don't.

   ► SE never reverses actions taken legitimately with privileges that are later lost when rep goes down (or the thresholds go up). So in itself, there's nothing flag-worthy about this.
2. It's their post, so they're allowed to comment on it.

   ► A comment from a user doing exactly what the software wants them to is not normally flag-worthy.
3. They posted a comment as an answer and a diamond took pity on them and converted it into a comment instead of just deleting it. (Which is what almost certainly happened here.)

   ► Don't flag things diamonds have already handled without good reason.
4. They posted a very short answer with a link that hit the auto-comment conversion heuristics and the software posted it as a comment instead of an answer.

   ► Usually, don't flag the products of automated software action, either.

All of these have the same action needed: none at all. If the software *lets* them post a comment as a comment, it's fine in general. Only if something else is wrong should you flag it, just like any other comment. Basically, it just doesn't matter how a comment got there. It's a comment. It's either fine or it's bad; either way, treat it accordingly.

Comment: The comment is quite longish, and it's more like an observation and a criticism rather than an answer but I've seen plenty of those type of answers being deleted, and not converted into a comment. I mean the comment, if it was originally posted as an answer, is not an answer or even a logical/sensible/funny comment, that why it caught my eye in the first place. I disagreed with the user's observation.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: If it's no good as a comment, there's no reason to worry about where it came from: flag it into the ground.

Comment: Still...the mod who declined my flag could have said that it was an answer converted into a comment. I realize, it's a bit tiresome, but I would have at least "known" why it had been declined.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Yeah, custom declines are always handy, but sadly quite rare. I wonder if one could get elected on a platform of more custom flag-handling messages....

Answer (score 6):

The issue here is that flags are for **"a human did a bad thing, please clean it up."** They are not for **"I think I found an anomaly or bug"**. Posts on meta are for that. A flag that says "this thing I see here must have been caused by a bug" should **always** be declined. Sure, it would be nice if the mod had replied "system is working as designed" but would that have actually helped you?

Answer (score 5):

A comment could be actually an answer later converted to comment by a mod (and it's not required for the "commenter" to have 50 rep).  Probably this is what happened to the comments you've run into.

If you have 10k, you can check it by looking down the answers. Those which have been converted to comments will have "converted to comment by ..." rather than "deleted by ...".

Comment: You mean an "answer" is converted as a comment. Oh, that could be it. I don't have the rep to see deleted answers.

Comment: @rene there will be.

Comment: @rene: I see those all the time. The only time no deleted answer is left is if it was a trivial answer with a link that gets auto-converted without mod intervention, but that's fairly rare.

Comment: @Nathan It doesn't work though when a user has less than 50 rep.

Comment: @nicael: Actually, I had that happen to me a few months back. Quite annoying. (There is no site that I have or had less than 50 rep, not since quite early last year.)

Comment: @Nathan I mean "less than 50 rep", edited the comment.

Comment: @nicael: Ah, OK. I haven't explored that side of things, but that makes more sense.