# Show all users if a post was converted to a comment, instead of just the owner

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, deleted-answers, convert-to-comment

When a user's post is converted to a comment, they see a message about it on the post itself:

[image: your post was converted to a comment; see the faq]

However, that only works for the post owner; other users see:

[image: Deleted by BoltClock ♦ 2 mins ago]

Is it possible to generalize the first message (e.g. "this post was converted to a comment") and show it to everyone? It's useful for 10k users/mods to know if a post was converted to a comment or just outright deleted

Comment: It would be nice if there was also some indicator on a comment that was converted from an answer.

Comment: @JeffMercado: Even something as subtle as the pencil that shows your comment has been edited, would help too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Done.

Starting with revision 2013.11.5.1120, if you can see the deleted post and are not the author of the post, you will see:

```
converted to a comment by <mod> <when>
```

Comment: Will it override [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98955/152859) i.e. show "converted to a comment by Community"?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - no. This specific case if for answers manually converted by a mod.