# Are we flagging (useless) jQuery answers now?

Tags: discussion, flags, deleted-answers

We've all seen the [jQuery meme.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19492#19492)  But are we flagging / deleting these types of useless answers now?  See the deleted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723329/facing-difficulty-with-javascript-getelementbyid/8724917#8724917) (10K):

[image: Screenshot of the answer]

Shouldn't answers like this just get downvoted?  Or was there some justifiable anger that this answer somehow garnered 3 upvotes?

**EDIT**

My confusion stemmed from the fact that this answer was converted to a comment (which I wasn't aware of).  Hopefully [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113386/show-all-users-if-a-post-was-converted-to-a-comment-instead-of-just-the-owner) will get implemented so this is a bit clearer for the next person.

Comment: Check the question, it was converted to a comment as it is

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113386/show-all-users-if-a-post-was-converted-to-a-comment-instead-of-just-the-owner)

Comment: @MichaelMrozek - that should absolutely be implemented.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's presumably true that the problem can be solved with jQuery, but most problems can be solved with many frameworks and languages.  Given that he didn't say *how* to do it with jQuery, I would have flagged it myself as ***not an answer***.  It's a comment (at best), and it was converted to one.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think it has anything to do with jQuery per se.  It just looks like that suggestion doesn't really answer the question.  It's best left as a comment instead.

Answer (score 6):

The [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) says:

> Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are …

- commentary on the question or other answers
- asking another, different question
- "thanks!" or "me too!" responses
- exact duplicates of other answers
- **barely more than a link to an external site**
- not even a partial answer to the actual question

The point I highlighted applies to this case.
It's not a matter of what the topic is, but a matter of the answer containing a little more than a link. Even supposing that the linked page contains the answer, the answer should at least make a summary about what reported in that page; it helps in the case that page is accessible for any reason, and doesn't force future readers to go to another site to read what they want to read.

Comment: Yeah - the main thing is that I didn't see that the answer was turned into a comment.  This was a fairly dumb question -- thanks for posting this though :)

Comment: I would not say it is a fairly dumb question. You asked an admissible question, asking if your suspects were true, or not.