# What is a "non-wiki answer" on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

What is "non-wiki answer" ? For example there's a badge:
Provided non-wiki answers of 15 total score in 20 of top 40 tags.
What answers are non-wiki?

Comment: Posts which aren't Community Wiki posts (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Comment: @Matt this can be posted as answer IMO as it clearly answers the question, maybe elaborate a bit by adding quotes from the faq page.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: I originally posted it as an answer, but it was auto-converted to a comment; I've elaborated a bit as you suggested and given the answer another go ;).

Comment: @Matt auto converted?? That's new to me.. cheers anyway now that you got it through. :-)

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98950/answer-appears-automatically-converted-as-a-comment/98955#98955

Comment: @Matt nice, never saw that. Another brain cell is now occupied. ;)

Comment: And "non-wiki" questions too

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Posts which aren't Community Wiki posts are deemed "non-wiki". For more info, see the FAQ section on ["What are 'Community Wiki' posts"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).

> Community Wiki posts work by transferring ownership of the post from the original author to the community. They make the post easier to edit and maintain by a wider group of users, but they do not contribute to any user's reputation.