# Trivial answer check doesn't handle short links to answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers

In trying to understand how [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554166/how-do-i-replace-white-spaces-from-the-string-in-android/11554174#11554174) made it past the [trivial answer checker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98950/answer-appears-automatically-converted-as-a-comment/98955#98955), I noticed that the operation that checks for the presence of a network link doesn't seem to consider the answer link short form (`/a/\d+`) as matching the criteria.

Posting the same answer with a full link to an answer or a short link to a question will trigger the auto-conversion to a comment, so the answer short link should as well.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/mYseM.png - Oh... wait a second...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This feature (trivial answer => comment) pre-dated the answer short-link format, thus why it wasn't included.

I've adjusted the check - it will take effect the next time we deploy (rev > 2012.7.18.3411)