# Suggested edits create loophole

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, new-users

A new user with less than 10 reputation points normally is not allowed to post two or more hyperlinks or images. The suggested edits feature allows them to bypass this restriction by suggesting an edit anonymously, and then using their post author vote to approve the changes.

One. [One link](http://google.com), ha ha ha. Two. [Two links](http://yahoo.com), ha ha ha. Three. [Three links](http://bing.com), ha ha ha. Four. [Four links](http://ask.com), ha ha ha.

[image]

Another example: [Answering StackOverflow questions without providing code snippet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152733/answering-stackoverflow-questions-without-providing-code-snippet/152738#152738)

Comment: while valid, seems like an overly complex workaround just to post a few links.  There are enough checks in the system that it shouldn't be a major issue.

Comment: This really doesn't seem "overly complex", and there are no checks for it. The fix seems to be to not allow people to approve edits they wouldn't have been able to make themselves

Comment: While it is a system limitation, there is nothing really that wrong with multiple links or images in a new user's post. If they are smart enough to work out the loophole then good on them.

Comment: What *is* wrong with a new user posting 10 links is that they are usually not very helpful but very spammy.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek "overly complex" might have been an overstatement, but it requires 3 steps to complete.  Just to post more than 2 links, it seems like a lot of effort for not much gain as a spammer is generally only going to post 1 or 2 links.  And as the OP, they should always retain final say on their post, so removing the ability to approve edits is not an ideal way to prevent this.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I didn't say "remove the ability to approve edits", I said "remove the ability to approve edits they wouldn't have been able to make themselves", which seems sane to me. Why should they be allowed to authorize someone else to do something they can't do themselves? I also have absolutely no idea why this question is getting not constructive votes, I must be missing something

Comment: @MichaelMrozek ok, I see your point... I interpreted what you said slightly differently than I think you meant it, so I stand corrected.

Comment: Good catch, I would suggest to not allow users with less than 10 reputation to approve suggested edits on their posts.

Comment: Recent real life example: [OP asks others to embed screenshots in question](http://superuser.com/revisions/496400/1), [low-rep user suggests edit which OP approves](http://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/45320). While this wasn't abuse, it doesn't make any sense.