# Error message about only using Jsfiddle, when code is included inline

Tags: bug, status-completed, jsfiddle

When posting an answer, I got an error: "Please made your answer complete by including relevant, formatted code inline (don't just link to jsfiddle.net)"

Even though I did include relevant code, just not enough?

[image]

Speaking from experience, sometimes the answer to a question is a typo or similar small issue.

I recognize that only posting links isn't good for the posterity of information, but it seems in its current state it is also throwing errors for valid answers.

Comment: There is more code in that fiddle though. You could just post the small amount of correct code you have there. I think that backtick doesn't count code either.

Comment: Related (and possible dupe) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code

Comment: I've just re-read that comment (and the really bad English in it). _"I think that a backtick doesn't count as code either."_  You need code tags, i.e. normally indented by 4 spaces.

Answer (score 3):

This was fixed along [with this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152855/ideone-paste-prevention-bug), check was just being too aggressive about what it consider "properly formatted code".

Answer (score 1):

This is a good thing. You should include *all* the relevant code in your question, and omit the JSFiddle link entirely.

Comment: If that were the case the site would just blacklist JSFiddle links

Comment: I would **love** to see that happen. JSFiddle links are a plague on Stack Overflow. I would be very happy if I never saw yet another Q/A derailed by turning into a series of revisions to a JSFiddle link.

Comment: @meagar: Blacklisting is a bit extreme. jsFiddle is very useful in quickly seeing exactly what's happening without 1) the OP showing their website they may not want to be public or flat-out can't show and 2) making others have to create an HTML page for something so small that it's borderline wasting time. Sure, we could educate users on **better use** of jsFiddle links, but blacklisting them causes more harm than good.

Answer (score 0):

> Speaking from experience, sometimes the answer to a question is a typo or similar small issue.

In such cases, the question should be closed as too localized. Knowing that the code shown in the question contains a typo is not much helpful for future readers.

You see that error because your answer is short, and it includes a link to jsFiddle. It should be read as "Please make your answer more complete, for example including relevant, formatted code inline (don't just link to jsfiddle.net)."
Making your answer more complete means, for example, explaining why OP's code is wrong, or why the solution you propose is better.

Then, as [meagar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/142838/meagar) said, using jsFiddle in such case is probably not necessary, to just say which CSS style the OP should use. Just write all the code you have in the jsFiddle into your answer. This is what you should do, if you really don't find anything else to add to make your question more complete.