# Ideone paste prevention bug?

Tags: bug, status-completed, quality-filter

When I was [answering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13109113/760746) this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108622/sum-of-consecutive-elements-in-an-array-c) I wanted to insert a link to ideone.com - where the code I wrote was used as a demonstration - and I encountered a message that said:

> Please make your answer complete by including relevant, formatted code inline(don't just link to ideone.com):

Screenshot:

> [image]

I could not put the link into the post because I would not be able to save it then.
As I did not just link to ideone but also inserted the code the message seems misplaced to me.

Why is it there?

**Edit**

Although I cannot be sure it seems I was not the only one with this problem. The author of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13108674/760746) to the same question seems to have used the same workaround as I did: Post the link as a comment.

Comment: Related: [Prevent posts with links to jsfiddle and no code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code)

Comment: That does indeed seem to be quite harsh with the amount of code you have posted. From the question I linked above: *"you'll be required to include some properly formatted code as well"*, which you seem to have done.

Comment: Other than the code block there is only really one line of text... Is that really enough to explain the issue?

Comment: @Lix: Even if it is not enough text, the message only talks about code and not about other text. So the explanation would be misleading.

Comment: @Lix That is however not the cause of the problem. Without the link the OP was able to post it just fine. Unless there is some mysterious inconsistent post length enforcement for posts containing such links.

Comment: This certainly should not happen, +1 and hope the devs will fix it quickly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This was a weird one.  Looks like, due to a combination of factors, your C++ code block there was successfully parsed as a URL.  Not as "containing a URL", but literally the whole thing as a single URL.

The "post code alongside ideone/jsfiddle links" check discards code blocks that *only* contain URLs, so you can't just post "Check out `http://jsfiddle.net/my-code`" or whatever.

The latest build has made that check considerably more conservative, so this shouldn't be happening anymore.  Kind of amazing that it was happening in the first place, really.

Comment: Then it seems I got an (un)lucky hand there.

Comment: Also I just inserted the link into the question to test if it works. As it does: +1 and accepted (until a better answer emerges :)

Comment: Could [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152787/error-message-about-only-using-jsfiddle-when-code-is-included-inline) be a related issue?