# "Don't just link to jsfiddle.net" when editing a post but not when asking the question?

Tags: support, edits, quality-filter, jsfiddle

I was trying to edit a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251170/issue-with-sliding-menu-on-hover) which had a jsfiddle link. The whole content was not just the link, but I believe there are other posts (like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152787/error-message-about-only-using-jsfiddle-when-code-is-included-inline), for example) that address this. Anyway, when I hit the Save Edits button, I got this error message -

> [image]

What I don't understand is, if this was a valid error, why was this error message not shown to the OP when he/she asked the question in the first place, thus providing for a more quality question in the first place? (I assumed it was not shown, because if it did, this post wouldn't have been in this shape.) Is it a bug, or could the OP have by-passed this error message (i.e. **if** it could be done - the OP seems to be a new user)?

Comment: Did you try editing it to fix the broken link? It may be that the current broken link wasn't detectable, but you edited it into a form that was.

Comment: you need to add relevant code ..it aint bug . its status by design [When jsFiddle and other related sites are gone, so is the information](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114942/when-jsfiddle-and-other-related-sites-are-gone-so-is-the-information)

Comment: @JeremyBanks: As hims056 suggested in the answer, I was trying to link the url to a word.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The OP did not get the error message because he/she used square brackets `[]` around the link like this [http://jsfiddle.net/eqkbR/9/]. So it is not a valid link and it is also not showing as a link. You probably tried to remove those square brackets thats why you got that error message. [I could edit the post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14251170/2) because I did not remove the those square brackets.

Comment: @卐웃ᙓᗢᓮᘐᓰﬡ웃卐 - it **is** the reason at all see [I could edit the post](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14251170/2). Now try to remove those square brackets....

Comment: @卐웃ᙓᗢᓮᘐᓰﬡ웃卐 - did not get. what do you mean by *edit is not working at all*?

Comment: That makes perfect sense, if it's in fact what's happening. Thanks, I did not know that!

Comment: @hims056 only fiddle link in question is not appropriated by so anymore we must include code

Comment: @卐웃ᙓᗢᓮᘐᓰﬡ웃卐 - Everyone knows that. But here OP (Chaithanya M) is asking that why that OP of [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14251170/1369235) could able to add link without code.

Comment: @hims056 ohh got it .. you are right that isnt even a link that is just a string ..