# Code detection heuristics for possible link-only answers should be a little bit smarter

Tags: feature-request, markdown, link-only-answers, jsfiddle

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17896922/366904) came up on my radar. The first thing I noticed about it was its inappropriate use of inline code formatting for something that is not code. Naturally, I tried to edit it:

[image: Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code.]

FOILED! Turns out, the answer is actually a link-only answer to an external resource, which [we've already decided is unacceptable and should be blocked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code). Great, I can support that.

But, if we're going to try, **it should not be *this* trivial to beat.**

You see, now I don't know if this was just one of those users who doesn't know what code formatting is used for, or if (s)he was using this to work around the smackdown put on link-only answers. If it was the former, they didn't even get a chance to ignore the good advice we're providing!

If you're posting a link to a jsFiddle, you're going to need *block-formatted* code; inline code simply won't do it. So why don't we check for that? When would inline code ever be enough?

Comment: If we'll do this, [such bugs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152787/152859) will start popping.

Comment: Geez, why do you need a jsFiddle demo for ***that***? @sha

Comment: Don't shoot the messenger, I'm neutral on this one. :)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17898428/1

Comment: Maybe we shouldn't allow `http` in the _rendered_ copy? It'd teach new users not to dump a link saying here it is.

Comment: @Cole Then you'd just get people posting links that aren't actually clickable. E.g.: jsfiddle.net/<number> What would that improve?

Comment: @CodyGray good point. What if it was detected that there was an `http`, it would require low rep users to make a Markdown link?