# Can't save question edit when replacing link with a jsfiddle

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits, jsfiddle

I was trying to edit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504766/child-position-differs-from-assigned-if-container-has-non-integer-position) by another user and replace the link demonstrating the problem with a link to jsfiddle instead to make experimenting with the problem easier.

However, the edit can't be saved. I only get the "don't just link to jsfiddle.net" error message. Is this intentional? Am I expected to add code examples as well after moving the code to a fiddle?

Comment: Don't **move** the code from SO.  If jsfiddle is offline the question would be useless. You may **copy** it though.

Comment: Since you get such a specific error message, it is very intentional.

Comment: @juergend: I'm not moving the code from SO, I was moving it from a *test file* on *the asker's own site*. Which I think is less likely to be around in the future than jsfiddle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, [it's intentional](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code) (hence the error message). And it's quite unfortunate that the system prevented a good edit, but the jsfiddle block is a good thing in general, the trend of "just a link to jsfiddle" pseudo answers was becoming unmanageable.

If you are still interested in editing the question, you should add the HTML source of the test script in the question text. Moving the code from test file on the asker's own site to jsfiddle is a good edit, but moving it to the question body is a far better one.