# Is posting a link to jsFiddle without code allowed again?

Tags: bug, status-completed, link-only-answers, jsfiddle

I recently stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996101/css3-jquery-animation), which [initially](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13996101/1) contained a link to jsfiddle.net but no code. Obviously the questioner had no problem posting it.

The link is active (not a plain text URL) and the whole question only consisted of the link and a paragraph of text. There was no formatted code, not even in backticks.

Has [this feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code) been retracted lately, or is this a bug?

Comment: jsFiddle isn't banned universally, only on ["super short posts"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151616/162704) (30 characters that aren't links).

Comment: @Yannis, my understanding of Kevin's answer is that they *tried* that, but it did not give the expected results and they switched to unconditionally requiring code with a link. Maybe I'm wrong, though.

Comment: Could it have been (quickly) edited in after the question was asked initially?

Comment: @Andrew, nope, [the feature applies to edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156634/164403). As it should.

Comment: That initial revision does not look very short to me. I suspect it is long enough to get past the requirement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Silly bug, wasn't accounting for the **www.**jsfiddle.net that was used in that post.

Changed some settings, and now everything should work as expected.

Comment: "www" is so last century.

Comment: *Follow-up:* Kevin, you may also want to exclude "fiddle.jshell.net", as it can be used to circumvent the block, as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26014709/464709).

Answer (score 0):

Such posts were always "allowed" by the system. The issue was with posts that are mainly just a link  (<30 plaintext chars).

One can ask a question of that length (it may even be a good one, though that's rare). Why should we block it if the question is of  that length and has an extra link?

In general, why should we block posts with no code but links to jsfiddle? The link could easily be only tangentially related to the question or a slightly relevant example.

The problem is not no-code-link-to-fiddle, it was question-too-tiny. Though the system's autoblocker is quite lenient while defining "tiny". 
Autoblocking should be done only when you're pretty sure that false alarms will be extremely rare. Which is not the case here, imho.

That being said, the question linked to *should* have inline code.  Though it has other issues as well.