# Editing a question with only a JSFiddle link does not work

Tags: support, stack-overflow, edits, jsfiddle

I can't edit a question that has a jsfiddle link because it has a lack of code. Can we get privileged users able to bypass restriction? The question had some really poor formatting and linking and I couldn't fix it.

[The question in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872580/html-is-not-taking-the-css-code):

> ## Html is not taking the css code
>
> Some of my html tags are not reacting by the css which i gaved them
> for example is offerbox not reaction to the html part. all html parts
> down from offerbox are not taking the styles that i gaved the
>
> ```
> enter code here http://jsfiddle.net/8Bw7M/
> ```
>
> pic from the html and css

I feel that as a privileged user, I should be able to make the changes needed.

This is related, but I'm not adding any new links.

[Can't save question edit when replacing link with a jsfiddle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156634/cant-save-question-edit-when-replacing-link-with-a-jsfiddle?rq=1)

Comment: I guess you tried to remove that placeholder and code markup? Yeah, that's by design.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby yea i think i should be able to fix it.

Comment: What I meant is, it is by design that it is not possible to only have a JSFiddle without code. And that OP bypasses that, and that no one inlines the code (looking at the, my dear no!) tells me that the question should be closed. Your example question, I fear, is no valid example on how this functionality is needed.

Answer (score 6):

This is not a bug, what you wanted to end up with was a link-only post, [which we explicitly discourage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92505/should-i-flag-answers-which-contain-only-a-link-as-not-an-answer).  If JS fiddle is offline then that question would be of no use.  Also, it's far less likely that Google could find the question.

Answer (score 4):

Any edit like that would qualify as "too minor" as it does not correct all visible problems with edited post. What's the problem to copy-paste from jsfiddle too? And if code is too big to do that, question should be closed due to lack of [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).