# JSFiddle links in code-block are recognized as valid inline code

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers, jsfiddle

I originally posted this as [an answer (10k only)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/163142/195761) to the feature-request [Prevent posts with links to jsfiddle and no code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149890/195761). Ben is uǝq backwards suggested to post this as a dedicated bug report because the original request has been completed already. That makes sense, so here we go:

I just discovered that some users already find their way around posting jsfiddle links without also adding some inline code into [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14243331/1521227):

[image]

So I suggest a code block containing jsfiddle links should not be counted as code block when ensuring that there's some inline code besides a jsfiddle link...

EDIT: I changed the meta-tag to [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) to encourage some more opinions on this topic, because this is not a bug, but a feature-request, if at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't see the need in adding workarounds for this. The user was most likely notified of needing code and chose to go this route instead of actually following the advice of the popup. Therefore, they clearly deserve their question to be closed, as they cannot even make a simple effort of adding code, and were warned before they even posted the question.

Covering all the workarounds for not allowing jsFiddle links without code is like covering all the different forms of "problem" to block from titles. Some people would just rather find obscure ways of bypassing the check instead of just fixing the problem to begin with; there's nothing you can do about that.