# What does "Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code." mean?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, error-message, jsfiddle

Why I can not save my question with this link?

```
Please check the [code][1]

Thanks!


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/tZFuX/2/
```

Comment: Because links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code **in the actual post**.

Comment: It's plain English... what word didn't you understand?

Comment: Lance Roberts gives the answer below; however note that a question that consists *only* of "Please check the code" and some code is not acceptable, either. It'll need to have *some* amount of description.

Comment: I was actually confused about it too. I thought it wanted me to mark the link as code, not add code from the jsfiddle link to the post

Comment: In KISS-speech it's "Linking to jsfiddle isn't allowed, copypaste all your code in the post instead".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They don't want you posting just a link.  You can post the link, but only if you post the code (or at least a relevant portion of it).

A full description of the reasoning behind this restriction can be found in [Prevent posts with links to jsfiddle and no code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code).

Comment: True, one big reason is that jsfiddle might vanish one day (judging by the fact that 99% of the time it's horribly slow that day might arrive soon) and then we'll stay with useless posts on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Here's why this rule is annoying: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667310/combined-area-of-overlapping-circles/16775721#16775721