# Do backticks count as code for jsFiddle links?

Tags: feature-request, support, code-formatting, jsfiddle

According to Kevin's answer to [Prevent posts with links to jsfiddle and no code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code):

> ... if you try and post to Stack Overflow with a link to either
>   jsfiddle.net or ideone.com you'll be required to include some properly
>   formatted code as well.

What is the definition of *"properly formatted code"* and does it include backticks?

[This revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15860415/1) contains nothing that I would consider code, yet has a jsFiddle link. It was posted yesterday so comes within the ambit of the completed request.

If backticks are "code" in this situation then this is a feature request to stop them from being considered as such.

Comment: Yes, backtick-formatted spans are considered as code in this context. I do support your feature request, "clever" questioners often use this implementation detail to avoid posting their code in the question.

Comment: Part of the problem is that they're not very "clever" @Frédéric :-). A question with no code is more likely to get closed and less likely to be re-opened as the OP of this question found. It's not actually that a bad question (though I have no idea if it's a duplicate or not) so if anyone does have knowledge of JS rotation in IE (or knows of a duplicate) please do help out the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, therefore you can `do` something like this and get the ability to stick a JSFiddle in there. (notice the code span for the word "do")

There are also workarounds like this:

---

blah blah this is a question

*(link to JSFiddle)*

```
Thanks for any answers
```

---

However this workaround is a lot more blatant. I think that JSFiddle should be only able to be submitted if there is a code **block**.

And what happens when people use the second workaround? Downvote and comment. (Don't just downvote, then the OP might not know why.)

Comment: *And what happens when people use the second workaround?* edit it out.

Comment: @juergend, you can't, unless you also copy the code from the fiddle into the question. The filter applies to edits.

Comment: I don't need advice on how to deal with jsFiddle links in questions or someone trying to get around the ban (this is all covered elsewhere anyway). This question is solely related to backticks and whether they count as code-blocks for the purposes of blocking question submission (your first sentence alone).