# jsfiddle only answers again

Tags: discussion, jsfiddle

Not so far ago SO implemented "no links to jsfiddle only please" restriction to answers and questions, now it is even worse. Users start to place jsfiddles like the following:

> please check my fiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/Kx4TS/19/`

Or they make a link to fiddle in the comments, which is more annoying than original behavior. Any ideas if it   come to be solved ?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175658/do-backticks-count-as-code-for-jsfiddle-links and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176902/dont-consider-inline-code-spans-as-code-for-the-purposes-of-the-quality-filter?lq=1 (both similar tricks)

Answer (score 3):

Just flag them as **Very Low Quality** - high-rep users will come along and delete them. One of the uses for VLQ is link-only answers

Comment: WE SHALL USE OUR BURNiNATION POWER TO BLOT OUT THE SUN!

Comment: Also, it isn't entirely clear whether or not to use VLQ for a link-only answer like this, see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183603/can-we-get-some-consensus-on-what-flag-to-use-for-link-only-answers

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I've been flagging them as VLQ, and have only had a few declined out of >5 dozen.

Comment: I guess I'm on the opposite of that scale, flagging as NAA for the last 3-4 months, and also rarely getting declines. It's not like it *really* matters though.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII My though is that the 10k'ers burn through them before the mods have a chance to decline them.

Comment: I've seen moderators advise NAA, VLQ, *and* a custom flag saying "link only answer," so... there's not really any consensus on this :P

Comment: Personally, I would accept a flag for such a post as NAA, VLQ, or Other, "link-only".

Comment: @AndrewBarber Could only you handle all my flags?