# Why aren't links to phpfiddle allowed?

Tags: support, external-sources

I have searched a while here on meta but wondered why I can't find an answer. I would like to know why it is not allowed to link to phpfiddle in an answer on Stack Overflow.

I could imagine that it isn't allowed because the elementary part of the answer should be on Stack Overflow and not on an external, maybe unreliable, resource. But sometimes it is really useful if the whole code is just to much to post or will divert from the answer itself, and is not so important but additionally nice to have.

Also I think I remember that links to other sites like phpfiddle (e.g. codepad, jsfiddle or sqlfiddle) are allowed.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code

Comment: @Mat Thanks! will read that (seems a lot of text) If I'm happy with the answers I'll delete this post

Comment: @Mat. As I said I encountered this is on a post with much effort and text and an additional link to phpfiddle

Comment: "much effort _and text_ and" - you need code too

Comment: @hek2mgl: phpfiddle links are allowed. Low quality posts are not.

Comment: I had code and text definitely. Maybe not *enough* code. But excuse me, the problem was just a single line in a bug bunch of code. :) But I now saw the discussion below the accepted answer there. Seems that I'm not alone :)

Comment: @Jim Thanks for fixing my grammar. I really appreciate to learn from that

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The code for a question should be short enough to reproduce the problem.  It shouldn't be any longer than that.

Code should be a 'point in time'. Code should (as you mention) be in the post so that if an external link goes down or changes, the question doesn't become useless.

You can always post a PHPfiddle or JSFiddle link as supplementary.

Major problems with JSFiddle (et.al.) include:

- Impermanence: Those links die. Those sites go down. Authors change their fiddles.
- Carte Blanche for the user to post a wall of code.
- Yet another hoop a user has to jump through to see an answer

Answers and questions **should not use an external link as their primary source**.

If a person visiting your question or answer can't just use the question or answer to solve their problem, that's an issue. As a moderator, I'll comment on or (more likely) delete posts that do not conform to these rather simple guidelines.

Comment: I'm with you with all what you said +1, but today I encountered a strange problem with that. I had code (an xpath query) and some text. And below a link to phpfiddle, where users could  try it with the real (big) xml data. The fact that it was not accepted made me a little bit unhappy as it took some effort to prepare the fiddle

Comment: @hek2mgl The crucial point is that you should only include enough code and data necessary to reproduce the problem. I find it hard to believe that the XML couldn't have been condensed down to that which reproduces the issue. It may have been more work for you, but it also means it's easier for others to follow.

Comment: Will take your advice, reducing the example xml to it's basics, in account in upcoming posts. Unfortunately I cannot reproduce my issue from today for you here. I encountered this the first time. Will play around with and find the required amount of code ;) However, now I know that the links are ok but must be substantiated with *enough* text and code. thanks for your answer and the discussion!

Comment: @hek2mgl Also, your CV in your profile 404s because it links directly to your edit page, and not your public CV URL.

Comment: Edited it yesterday, and tested it poorly. Will update! thanks, that was nice! Updated the link. If you are searching for developers .... :)

Comment: is there any chances to provide phpfidle in  so question only?

Comment: how is that possible to share a phpfiddle project?

Answer (score 4):

**The links to PhpFiddle are allowed**, but make sure, that you write some code in your answer, because external sites can't be relied on. So if the external site is not accessible, a reader of your answer must have the same code available on Stack Overflow. Otherwise, your answer in this case is of no use.

The fiddle has to be just to support your answer in the form of a demo of your code.

For example, see [Rab Nawaz's answer to *Getting in trouble while splitting a string in PHP*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085180/getting-trouble-while-splitting-string-in-php/17085245#17085245).