# Ban JSBin, Codepen, etc. links without code too

Tags: discussion, feature-request, jsfiddle

A user may not post a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) link if the user doesn't also post some code with it. <sup>[(link)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code)</sup> I recently learned that [this is the same with PHPFiddle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179416/why-arent-links-to-phpfiddle-allowed).

Why isn't this ban in place with all the other sites similar to JS/PHPFiddle, like [JSBin](http://jsbin.com), [Codepen](http://codepen.io), [IDEOne](http://ideone.com), [CodePad](http://codepad.org),  etc.?

Comment: Talk about whack-a-mole.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I know, but you could at least ban the most common ones (the ones I see most are IDEOne, JSBin, and Codepen)

Comment: I can't ban anything; code wise that determination is made by the SE team.  I'm sure they have a banned domains list, but I can't add or remove domains from it.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Well yes, by "you" I meant "the people who do that kind of stuff" :P

Comment: If you're keeping track of examples, here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22078847/revisions. Have an upvote from me.