# Prevent posts with links to fiddle.jshell.net (same as jsFiddle) and no code

Tags: discussion, feature-request, jsfiddle

Apparently you can link to http://fiddle.jshell.net/ which is really literally, exactly the same as http://jsfiddle.net/ without posting code of any kind.

Can posts with links to http://fiddle.jshell.net/ and no code be prevented seeing as how it is just another road to http://jsfiddle.net/?

---

Example of the issue:
[Why is drag & drop so much smoother when adding "overflow: auto"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191793/jquery-with-overflow-auto-updated)

Strongly Related:
[Prevent posts with links to jsfiddle and no code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code)
[Ban JSBin, Codepen, etc. links without code too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184327/ban-jsbin-codepen-etc-links-without-code-too)

Comment: Won't there be a never ending parade of these types of sites? You can maintain manual lists but people took about 3 seconds to get around the previous block. Surely it's better to just ensure that they're downvoted and closed quickly, which an empty close queue will help with immeasurably. (or embed the code from them somehow)

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards very true, but if the user isn't using jshell to deliberately workaround the filter it may help to show the popup and prevent the behavior to begin with, rather than wasting reviewer time and energy.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I would prefer to be able to just flag these, but that seems to have been a somewhat fruitless discussion.

Comment: Even worse: the JSFiddle folks might some day drop that odd domain, which might break in the future.

Comment: @Arjan turns out you were right. You can no longer use [fiddle.jshell.net](https://fiddle.jshell.net/404) to replace a [JSFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net) link. In the linked question, the link is now broken.