# Plunker should be "banned" just like jsFiddle

Tags: feature-request, link-only-answers, jsfiddle

Plunker (http://plnkr.co/) seems to be a more feature-rich alternative to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) (it seems to be *especially* popular with AngularJS developers, probably because you can "host" multiple files there, which is useful for templates). It's a very good site and certainly useful.

But since we often ended up with incomplete questions, because code was *only* posted on jsFiddle, we ended up [disallowing posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151616/40342) with jsFiddle links that don't *also* contain code.

And I simply think that Plunker should share the same fate.

Some examples:

- [Why doesn't this nested angular-ui-router work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616396/why-doesnt-this-nested-angular-ui-router-work)
- [$scope.$watch in Controller not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17707755/scope-watch-in-controller-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: And yet another "whack a mole" game starts.  Just vote to close as *"Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem and include valid code [in the question] to reproduce it. See SSCCE.org for guidance."* or flag the question and explain the problem.

Comment: That "in the question" sounds like a feature request @RobertHarvey. It would be a useful addition to the current message.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, but is it really that hard to whack this particular mole? Based on the answer to the other question, this is already done for *jsfiddle* and *ideone*, seems like adding *plnkr* would be as simple as updating a list, no?

Comment: @BenLee: Upvoted. How many could there possibly be? :))))

Comment: [CodePen](https://codepen.io), [CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.org/), [CodePad](http://codepad.org)…

Comment: Just create a post to list these in (in meta), mark it community wiki, then have a script that sweeps everything in that list with at least three upvotes or whatnot into your table of excluded things.  :)

Comment: Hmm: [jsFiddle for other languages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721298/jsfiddle-for-other-languages), [Are there tools similar to JsFiddle for other languages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456765/are-there-tools-similar-to-jsfiddle-for-other-languages), [Any other choice besides jsfiddle.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895371/any-other-choice-besides-jsfiddle-net). A lot more moles than I realized, but I doubt most of them post an actual problem with rampant abuse on SO.

Comment: @Bart: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189236/add-the-words-in-this-question-to-the-questions-require-code-close-reason

Comment: Thank you for the close/delete fodder @BenLee :-). Sad thing is they all missed http://repl.it/ and http://www.sqlfiddle.com :-(.

Comment: In fact, here's two more to add to the Wednesday evening off-topic question massacre: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660581/something-like-jsfiddle-for-vbscript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434578/jsfiddle-alternative-on-mobile

Comment: Would like to bump this question as Plunkr seems to be down again.. (sign-in with github failure)