# What to do if I can't save an answer with a linked fiddle, that is not a relevant part of it

Tags: discussion, answers, jsfiddle

Of course I've read "[Prevent posts with links to jsfiddle and no code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149890/190341)" and I totally agree to avoid answers like:

> See [here](http://jsfiddle.net).

But now I'm in an odd situation.

I just [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18276333/1456376) the question "[Way around to hide parent if :visited link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18275615/1456376)". As there's no solution to that problem using the technologies the OP asked for, there's of course no valid source code to put into the answer. Nevertheless I've created a simple fiddle for clarification and to demonstrate that the code will fail. When I linked the fiddle I couldn't save my answer, unless I included some code.

So I ended up adding some code, that is actually not useful to answer the question. And now I have two possibilities:

- Leave it as it is. Which may lead unobserving users to actually think that this is possible solution.
- Add a textblock and explain, that this code will not work and was added only to make the answer self-contained and to demonstrate the failure.

Somehow both don't feel right. What would you recommend in such a case?

Comment: your fiddle is empty...

Comment: If your post is intended to provide clarification and demonstrate that the OP's code will fail, is it an answer? Would it work better as a comment?

Comment: @Rikard - really? Tested it from different browser and the link seems to be OK and the fiddle is working. That's strange.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins There's no code involved in the question. The answer explains that and why it is not possible to solve the problem. I think this is a legitimate reason to answer instead of comment. The fiddle is only in addition to demonstrate that no matter what you try it really won't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either include the code that you included in the fiddle, so that it can be useful for whatever reason you included the fiddle, or, if the code that you have in the fiddle *won't* be useful, then it seems like a rather strong indication that you shouldn't be including it in the first place.

If the information in the fiddle isn't a part of your answer, in that it answers the question just fine without the fiddle, and the fiddle is really just a bid of a tangent; some side information, then that information may fit better as a comment.  Comments are designed to add additional information that isn't strictly an answer to the question.  (You can of course add the comment in addition to an answer that *does* answer the question.)

Comment: That was my solution: First choice is to put the vital lines from the fiddle, the ones that prove it can't be done, in the answer. Second choice: write up the answer that meets everyone's needs, then add a comment "a fiddle demonstrating this is at...".

Comment: Yeah. Why didn't I think of that. I agree. Adding it as a comment to my own answer is the most suitable thing to do. Thanks.