# How to moderate questions with only a misformatted link to jsfiddle and no code

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, policy, jsfiddle

**Context**

I've come to medium-low-quality questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359491/scrolling-div-fixed-until-footer)

Which contains only a *misformatted* link to jsfiddle, and no code.

I understand, from [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code), that this is a bad practice, and a feature has been implemented specifically to educate users on this topic.

In the questions I came across, the formatting of the jsfiddle link was (on purpose ?) wrongly formatted, which prevented the detection system to work.

**My question**

How should I address the post on a moderation point of view ?

Options I thought of:

1. Leave a comment to the question, saying "please insert some code"
2. Flag for moderator attention (I think moderators have enough to do !)
3. Don't care (After all, if jsfiddle goes down, the question will stay unanswered).

Comment: I'd definitely at least leave the comment

Comment: There's a sub-reason of "offtopic" that states that the question doesn't include a reproducible code sample, and/or doesn't adequately describe the problem.  Seems to be a perfect fit for this question, since (based on my reading) it can't really be answered with the information currently there.

Comment: Add a comment and vote to close (if you have the power)

Comment: Shouldn't such questions be caught by the quality filter anyway?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best option would be to edit the post to add the code from the jsfiddle, and leave a comment explaining this to the OP.

If you can't do that for some reason (such as there being way too much code), then what I usually do is downvote and explain in the comments about the policy and that you will undownvote once the code is edited into the question.

Also consider closevoting with this reason:

> Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Answer (score 2):

I would exercise a little case by case discretion, if it is a brand new user who doesn't know any better, I would go ahead and edit in the code. On the other hand if it is a more experienced user who should know about the filter and appears to be deliberately subverting it I would flag or vote to close.

Comment: Editing the code in in this case would do nothing, as there is no JavaScript/jQuery code in that fiddle.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby sorry talking in more general terms. I've seen users deliberately subverting the filter by adding empty code blocks and the like.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby cases like this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181433/217863