# linking common messages on SO to metaSO

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Can we put a link to Error Message explanation so other users can understand.

For example, I am talking about following error message

[image]

If we can put link to [Prevent posts with links to jsfiddle and no code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code) in the message , then user might be able to understand he needs put code on both SO and jsfiddle.

Comment: No need for such a thing, it's in the same "level" as missing title or body. If one want further explanation he'll come to Meta and search. :)

Answer (score 4):

> Links to jsfiddle.net must be accommpanied by code.

To be fair, that's a very explicit message, and I'm not sure what more could be elaborated on a dedicated page or link to a meta post or whatever other than the *reasons* behind not allowing it.

Evidently the OP knows what jsfiddle.net is - indeed, they're using it, so let's hope so! - and presumably the OP also knows what code is - as it happens, if they don't then the situation is all the more dire and a link to anywhere is not going to help in the slightest. So, the message ought to quite clearly make one *'able to understand he needs put code on both SO and jsfiddle'*, but it needn't make them able to understand *why* this is a requirement, as that's a different thing.

You have a problem, illustrate it in jsfiddle.net, illustrate it as concisely as possible in the post (as per the prompt, if it was needed), and there you are. There's nothing really much to it.

Comment: you are right Grant but the problem is i have seen more then once because of this kind of message user is not putting jsfiddle link correctly

Comment: Then, without sounding too callous, these need to understand their level of ignorance and address that.

Comment: ok sorry Grant i think i will delete the question after 30 min or so .. but what i thought this might be a small change and can help many as most of the users are new when they ask question