# Link to ideone.com in /help/how-to-ask

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, help-center

Minor suggestion: In https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask there is a bullet point that reads:

> If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can *link* to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so ...

I think that http://ideone.com would be a good addition to the "for example" list.

It would give a nice complete set of tools; in addition to SQL and HTML + JavaScript, it would round it off with all the languages ideone supports, which, at the time of this writing, includes:

> Bash, Pascal (fpc), C, Pascal (gpc), C#, Perl, C++ 4.8.1, PHP, C++11,
>   Python, Haskell, Python 3, Java, Ruby, Java7, SQL, Objective-C,
>   VB.NET, Ada, COBOL 85, Intercal, Perl 6, Assembler, Common Lisp
>   (clisp), JavaScript (rhino), Pike, Assembler, D (dmd), JavaScript
>   (spidermonkey), Prolog (gnu), AWK (gawk), Erlang, Lua, Prolog (swi),
>   AWK (mawk), F#, Nemerle, R, bc, Factor, Nice, Scala, Brainfuck,
>   Falcon, Nimrod, Scheme (guile), C++ 4.3.2, Forth, Node.js, Smalltalk,
>   C99 strict, Fortran, Ocaml, Tcl, CLIPS, Go, Octave, Text, Clojure,
>   Groovy, Oz, Unlambda, COBOL, Icon, PARI/GP, and Whitespace.

Not bad for one extra link!

Comment: But have we yet blocked posts that consist only of ideone.com links with no accompanying code blocks?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn The gist of the help center article is that those tools are useful *in addition* to posted code, not in lieu of. That is  correct and should not change.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian I'm not a web programmer so I can't really agree with you there. :-) But looking at it it does seem superior to jsbin, doesn't it?

Comment: [Ideones's FAQs](https://ideone.com/faq) say "How long my codes [sic] will be stored on Ideone? Forever". However, most of my old links stopped working - for example this http://ideone.com/YRZE5 from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9942766/7586), and many other links from my blog. Is Ideone a reliable resource?

Comment: @Kobi I've generally found it to be reliable. However, I've sent an email to them to ask (waiting on response) and I also grabbed [every ideone.com link](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/174231/posts-that-contain-ideone-links) on SO and am going down the list checking them for validity. I'll let you know when it's done (might be awhile, there are ~12k and I don't want to get rate limited by their server). Note that the help page goes on to say *"... but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time."*

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn (By the way: [Yes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151616/230261), presuming that behavior is still in effect.)

Comment: I agree. Even though I'm not an avid user of ideone (since I'm mostly SO-ing in front of my computer with IDE already open), I have used it and indeed it's helpful. For reliability, I don't think it will be a problem, since in any case, the important code has to be posted on question/answer in the first place. My opinion is to use ideone.com **as working sample/demonstration only**.

Comment: I have found that about 2/3 (8709 of 12757) ideone links on SO are still valid. 95% of the links after Feb 1, 2012 are valid; 11% of the links prior to that date (Sep '08 - Jan '12) are valid. It appears there is roughly a 2 year cut-off -- since there *are* valid links before that date, it may relate to "last accessed". ( @Kobi )

Comment: @JasonC - Thanks for the research! So can we safely assume there will be no further deletions? I just stopped using it when I saw old items are deleted...

Comment: @Kobi I'm not sure if it's safe to assume there will be no more deletions, but evidence suggests that it's safe to assume links will last at least 2 years (and possibly longer if they are viewed). Still waiting on a reply from their support.