# Not Gaining reputation

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-answers

Hi I am answering the questions and users are upvoting my answers in SO but still I have not gained any reputation nor it is showing the questions that I have answered in my profile webpage.

Comment: Link all posts you have answered

Comment: It looks like all of your posts may have been deleted. ([Here's one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14684032/1114).)

Comment: And [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868397/secure-communications-with-ssl-only-used-for-log-in#comment-20844024) is your trivial answer which is converted to comment.

Comment: But what about the reputation I gained, it was nearly 30 on 1st day and I was able to cast vote but now all is gone.

Comment: Yep, deleting answers remove rep.

Comment: @LanceRoberts, I don't think that it is prejudice, nor gratuitous text, it is [entirely reasoned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259).

Comment: @Benjol, prejudice isn't always a bad thing, though I don't like that particular one.  I understand the reasoning, and usually add verbiage myself to back up the link, but __terseness should be appreciated.__

Comment: @LanceRoberts, definitely, but *self-contained* terseness.

Comment: @Benjol, agree, it's an art (that I haven't necessarily mastered myself).

Comment: May I also say, please don't have your coworkers selectively vote for your posts (and likewise, don't just vote for their answers). Votes need to come based on a post's technical merit, not the person leaving it.

Answer (score 8):

One of [your answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14684032/1114) is deleted (as mentioned by [Jeremy Banks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167530/not-gaining-reputation#comment-492695)). And one of your trivial answer is [converted to comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868397/secure-communications-with-ssl-only-used-for-log-in#comment-20844024).

So you don't gain/lose reputation on deleted posts. And also you don't gain/lose any reputation by comments. Reputation changes from votes (both up and down) on deleted posts (including answers to a deleted question) [are nullified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/187824) (except [an exception](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/)).

Comment: I don't see a deleted answer for the post which you claim was converted to a comment. AFAIK conversion to comment leaves behind the answer in deleted form.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - Because it is auto converted comment. (Directly converted when you click on `Post Your Answer`)

Comment: For the second answer, I think you mean to point to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684291/default-value-should-be-stored-at-insertion/14684340#14684340 , which was a comment left as an answer.

Comment: @BradLarson I am talking about the comment I have linked. I can't see deleted answer.

Comment: @hims056 - They had a second answer that was really a comment, which was removed. I thought that might be what you were talking about. The auto-converted one wouldn't have accumulated any votes to begin with, but these deleted ones did.

Answer (score 3):

As already stated

- You won't gain/loss reputation on deleted answers/questions
- No reputation change on comment vote either

Now going through 2 of your answers, the [first one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14683986/connection-with-proxy-internet-for-update-in-ubuntu-12-04/14684032#14684032)  is more like a clarification in a question (which is off topic also), and you should use comment field for that kind of purpose. It was simply not an answer, and so moderator deleted it.

The [second one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868397/secure-communications-with-ssl-only-used-for-log-in#comment-20844024) is a link only answer, and which [are discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143642/cant-link-only-answers-be-auto-deleted-instead-of-showing-up-in-the-review-queu) here on SO. Your post should answer the question even if the link goes dead, which is not the case with your answer. So it is converted as a comment.