# High-rep users should be exempt from answer-to-comment autoconversion

Tags: feature-request, privileges, moderators, convert-to-comment

Currently, a short, machine-identified-as-seemingly-low-quality answer is automatically converted to a comment on the question.

[gbn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/27535/gbn) [has suggested in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98950/answer-appears-automatically-converted-as-a-comment#comment251193_99096) that this be "weighted for, say, user rep". I'd like to propose that formally, so am opening this feature request. Specifically: **Any [user with 10000 rep](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) or moderator should not have his short answers automatically converted** to comments. Such a user recognizes what makes a good answer and what doesn't, and if he decides [it should be an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99096) then that should be weighted more than the autodetector. (Of course, the answers could still be moderator-converted.)

Comment: I thought this must have been proposed before, but [apparently not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convert-to-comment+feature-request).

Comment: What makes you think that high rep users and mods don't have answers that should be comments?

Comment: @bluefeet, hopefully they recognize what makes a good answer and what doesn't, and if they decide it should be an answer then that should be weighted more than the autodetector. I've edited the rationale into my question; thanks for making me clarify.

Comment: So, it's OK for mods and higher rep users to be lazy. Thanks ;)

Comment: @msh210 Unfortunately that line of reasoning doesn't always hold up in practice.

Comment: So if a 10K user/mods posts a link-only answer it should stay because  "they recognize what makes a good answer and what doesn't"

Comment: @HugoDozois, it shouldn't be *autoconverted*. It could still be edited or mod-converted. The theory is that such a user wouldn't normally be posting such an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure about this one... can you give examples of posts that currently qualify for auto-conversion that shouldn't be auto-converted? And, for that matter, why wouldn't we just upgrade the detector to allow "good" short answers from everyone while continuing to restrict "bad" short answers from everyone as well? I don't see how rep comes into play here, I guess.

Comment: @PopularDemand, for examples see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99096. I don't know how well a script can tell good from bad answers. I suspect very badly.

Comment: Hmm, okay, I see where you're coming from now. I'm still not 100% on board -- I suspect that your example is the edge case, not the common one -- but have an upvote for an interesting proposal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

High reputation users still post crappy one-line answers instead of closing as a duplicate as they should do. The auto-conversion does its job pretty well in most cases, though there are certainly some tweaks that could be made.

The only time I ever ran into it was on a per-site meta, where a short answer with a link to the canonical answer on Meta.SO would be a complete answer. On the main sites the script seems to work well in my observation.

The user experience when you get a post converted could also be better, but maybe that has improved in the mean time. The only time I ran into this, I posted my answer twice until I noticed that it was converted into a comment.

Comment: Well, this proposal doesn't seem very popular (at the moment, judging by the comments, answers, and votes). Perhaps I'll post a duplicate of it, but restricting to per-site metas (and maybe mods), then. That's where I've noticed it, also.

Comment: @msh210 I don't think exception based on user rep or mod-status are useful, but eliminating some corner cases makes sense in my opinion. It is a pretty bad user experience if such a conversion is triggered in an inappropriate case.

Comment: Well, on the per-site metas, the mods sort of interface between MSO and the users to some extent... so it may make sense for mods to be exempt.

Comment: @msh210 I hit the autoconversion on a site where I'm not a mod, regular users also often link MSO posts. Making exceptions for mods makes a lot of sense in many cases, but I don't think we mods should be exempt from the basic quality criteria for posts, as that could set a bad example.

Answer (score 10):

**No.**

And here's why:

[image]

Higher rep users make mistakes too.

Comment: Everyone errs sometimes and, as you demonstrate here, 10K users are likely to catch and fix it themselves. This example is support for my proposition.

Comment: @msh210 And what if they _don't_ catch it?

Comment: @Telthien What if anyone doesn't catch anything? Lots of likely-poor-quality posts are not autoconverted: they get flagged. Only a specific set of likely-poor-quality posts are autoconverted, and I was proposing that that set be made a little smaller.

Comment: @msh210 Ah, but as you can see in my example, the poor quality answer was _not_ autoconverted. Perhaps that set should be made a little larger instead?

Comment: @msh210 You've gone from "What if one person doesn't catch one thing?" to "What if _nobody_ catches _anything_?"

Comment: @Yannis, `:-)` perhaps. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175849/high-rep-users-should-be-exempt-from-answer-to-comment-autoconversion/175851?noredirect=1#comment527528_175853.

Comment: @Telthien, no I said "doesn't catch anything" meaning there's something else not caught, not meaning nothing else is caught.

Comment: @msh210 Of course there will be. No automatic system is perfect. But, would you rather have some or none caught?

Comment: @Telthien, I'd rather have the ones caught that really are low in quality. I think that's what everyone wants. My proposal is/was an attempt to approximate that more closely.

Comment: This should really have been a comment