# How Can A User With 1 Rep Comment On A Post?

Tags: bug, reputation, comments, privileges

This is weird. A possible bug perhaps?

But I came across this question on SO: [Center checkbox programitcally?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16248751/450534) which has 2 comments. One of which is by a user [ashishdhiman2007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2301721/ashishdhiman2007). I accidentally hovered over his name link and saw that he has just the 1 rep.

I quickly opened the [Comment Everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) Privileges page to check if something has changed that I haven't seen yet. But it still reads *Reputation Required: 50*

Plus this important part of the page:

> Please note that you can always comment on your own posts, and any
>   part of your questions. However, commenting on other people's posts is
>   a privilege.

This question **is** someone else's post which makes me wonder if it is a possible bug.

Is this a possible bug?

Attaching a screenshot (just in case):

> [image]

Comment: In this case surely a LOA is converted into comment automatically. and in other situations a person having enough reputations to post a comment...commented but later lost he looses all his reputation and now comes to floor of 1 reputation.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: But won't the privilege be revoked if the user was to loose some reputation if he / she were to fall below the necessary rep for it? In this case, as soon as I go down to, say 49, I should be loosing my _Comment Everywhere_ privilege right?

Comment: See the example, you got 52 reps, you commented on a post. And in few days you lost all reps. now you are having 1rep, but your comment will be there. May be from a bad question, which is now deleted.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: Yes. The comment will remain after loosing rep and falling below the necessary requirement. But if you were to look the user's profile and the question, he posted it 11 minutes back (screenshot) and the profile shows that he has neither gained any rep nor lost any. Which is what prompted me to post a question here.

Comment: I agree with @AnoopVaidya, this specific case is probably a link-only answer converted to a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like he posted a link only answer which is automatically [converted to comments.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98950/187824) So it's not a bug. It's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Related meta tag: [convert-to-comment](/questions/tagged/convert-to-comment)

Comment: That happens? Aren't such _answers_ just removed? Perhaps, it is time for me to take a day off and read just _Meta_ for the entire day. :-)

Comment: Aah ha. That settles it then. Thanks for sorting that out. Tomorrow seems like a good day to read up on meta then. :-). So will someone change the _bug_ tag to the _status-bydesign_ tag or should I be the one to do it?

Comment: @IceMAN - If we convert his link only answer into comment, he will be encouraged to add comments instead of link only answers, if we allow such answers to be posted and then remove it by reviewing, the poster will not be encouraged to add a comment instead of link only answers. :)

Comment: @IceMAN - We can't edit status tags only moderators can do it. :) So leave it.

Comment: Check and check. You did mean leave it for the _bug_ tag used in my post above right?

Comment: @IceMAN - Yes. Moderator will do it for you.