# Stack Overflow calls my short answer "trivial"

Tags: feature-request, comments, answers, wording, convert-to-comment

I wrote a short answer today, and I was a bit miffed when Stack Overflow called it trivial and turned it into a comment.

I think it's fine to turn a short answer into a comment, but I think the adjective should be changed to "short" or at least "perfunctory".

Comment: Hmm... I guess 'trivial' might sound a little more harsh than needed.

Comment: *As a courtesy to you, your short, pithy answer has been automatically converted to a comment to conform to our community-friendly site guidelines.  Thank you for your contribution, and have a wonderful day!*

Comment: +1 to SO for not speaking of agricultural implements.

Comment: "Perfunctory" has a worse connotation than "trivial". It means you don't care and are barely even making an effort.

Comment: "Half-assed answer converted to comment." @Josh

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98950/answer-appears-automatically-converted-as-a-comment

Comment: Trivial is defined as "of little value or importance". Perhaps this can be taken as derogatory by some, although I think that if your answer was deemed trivial then perhaps it needs more substance. Some alternative words for consideration: exiguous, sparse, lightweight.