# Is the auto-conversion of some answers to comments a bug that can be used to comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, gaming-the-system

When I had very little reputation on Stack Overflow and I wanted to comment a clarification to somebody else's answer, I wrote a bad quality "answer" that had my comment in it, which would then be picked up by the script and turned automatically into a comment. Should this be fixed to completely prevent people with low reputation from commenting or should it remain?

Comment: `be picked up by the script and turned automatically into a comment` <<- a mod converts your answer to a comment I think - not the system. Also, what do you mean 'should this be fixed`? - Should what be fixed?

Comment: When you have about 10 reputation and have a very short answer, when you click "Answer Question", it asks you if you want to make it better. If you choose to leave it like it is, it is sometimes made into a comment.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ, The system will automatically convert certain types of answers to comments.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98950/answer-appears-automatically-converted-as-a-comment

Comment: It really isn't a bug > It's a feature!

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in your title - Yes, auto-converting low-quality answers into comments *can* technically be used by low-rep users to write comments.  They can also 'use' a moderator's ability to convert short answers into comments to write comments.

This is not a bug - it is a feature of the site that allows users who would otherwise be posting low-quality answers to contribute comments.  It also isn't exactly a 'workaround' to prevent low-quality comments, as moderators can still remove problematic comments and opt to delete answers before they become comments in the first place.

In short, yes it CAN be used that way, but in part it is supposed to work that way, and any abuse that results from it working that way can easily be fixed.

Comment: Easily fixed once detected, sure.  But easily detected?  Not so much -- it's not really obvious that this has been done, unless you think to check specially for it.

Comment: @D.W. And if it has been done so that someone with low-rep can make a comment on a post, that isn't so wildly offensive that it immediately gets flagged as inappropriate, this really isn't an issue at all.  Immediate mod attention is only really necessary if the comments being made are problematic in and of themselves.  For someone who really just wanted to comment on a question anyway, converting an answer to a comment is the appropriate action.