# How can I prevent my "trivial" answer from being converted to a comment?

Tags: support, comments, convert-to-comment

Now that the [maximum tag length has been increased to 35](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11018/can-we-please-increase-our-tag-length/11236#11236), I've been spending some time browsing older retag requests to see which ones can now be completed.

[On one such request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253564/i-just-found-a-tag-which-was-cut-off-can-it-be-fixed#autocomment502287), I tried posting the following answer:

> Now that the [maximum tag length has been increased to
>   35](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11018/can-we-please-increase-our-tag-length/11236#11236),
>   I see no reason why this tag can't be fixed.

I was then notified "Trivial answer converted to comment".

In this scenario, I think this is a significant enough development that it should be posted as an answer, and not as a comment.

How can I prevent my answer from being auto-converted to a comment?

Comment: "I've just checked - that tag cannot be fixed as there is a maximum length of 25 chars for tags. So no, it can't be fixed, it's a status-bydesign." seems just as trivial an answer short so perhaps the auto-change rules have been adjusted or....  So all I can guess is maybe add a screen shot?

Comment: @iBug I don't think this is duplicate. It does not ask "why" but rather asks to challenge/cancel this feature so that OP can post trivial answers. It's more of a feature request actually. (So I also downvoted since I believe this feature is just fine and trivial answers should not be posted)

Answer (score 1):

I used a [wording that was not much longer and only slightly changed from what you tried](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354742/820534), and was able to add an answer to that same question successfully.

I recommend trying to always answer with more than a single sentence.

With any one line answer, I think you run the risk of it attracting downvotes and/or a post notice (and possibly later deletion) for providing insufficient explanation.

Comment: I kinda wanted to post the answer myself...

Comment: @StevenVascellaro I was trying to provide you, and later readers, with a workaround in case you encountered the same problem again. I thought the best way to do that was by showing one that works.

Answer (score -3):

From [*Kevin Montrose*'s answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98955/350567):

> Trivial answers **containing a link to another question in the network** are automatically converted to comments on the question, with the message

You may want to add more details (just a little more) so that your answer is longer and does not fit in the "trivial" criterion.

---

I believe the current criterion for conversion is all below:

- The formatting is totally acceptable in comment

  - <s>no paragraph or linebreak</s> (will be stripped)
  - no `<pre>` block or quote block

    - If you use `<pre>` or `<blockquote>`, your answer will still be converted, however. Use 4-space indentation and `>` instead. See HTML below.
  - no image
  - <s>no `<kbd>` tag</s> (See HTML below)
  - no lists (ordered/unordered)
  - <s>no HTML formatting (i.e. MD only)</s> (will be forcibly ignored)
  - <s>not so long</s> contains no more than 2 sentences (Comma is OK)
  - ......
- Contains links, but only link to other posts (Q or A) in the network.

  In other words, answer with no link *OR* with an external link (e.g. Google) will not be converted.

So you may want to format your answer so that it doesn't meet the criteria above.

Comment: I understand that sometimes a very short answer is all that's needed, but using formatting tricks to bypass the check is abusive. Please don't.

Comment: I think it is a lot easier to just treat "about two sentences" as being a minimum length answer.