# Does CW posts count towards post ban?

Tags: support, community-wiki, post-ban

When testing the "trivial answer" criterion for [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299499/350567), I submitted quite a few answers to the Sandbox. Since the answers are intended to be "trivial", I feel like deleting them. However ,I am afraid I might be banned from answering if I have too many deleted answers. So my question is:

Does CW posts (Qs and As) count towards the post ban to the author of them?

Personally I believe so, but I want official confirmation (or others' experiences).

I'd like it if Sandbox posts are exempt from the post ban, as long as they're not flagged as spam or rude/abusive. (Sandbox always accepts off-topic posts but not offensive ones.)

Comment: Why wouldn't they? The point of the ban is to stop you from wasting people's time with multiple low-quality posts. Whether these posts are CW or not doesn't seem relevant. That said, the ban thresholds are more relaxed on Meta, I don't think you are in danger of getting banned.

Comment: @yannis If you have citation or reference, post an answer please.

Comment: The inner workings of the post bans are intentionally kept secret, not sure how much of an "official confirmation" you can expect here. But, you might be on to something here. Technically CW posts aren't "owned" by a single user, so they might be ignored by the post ban.

Comment: @yannis I believe CW has a "owner" (1st poster). Under CW questions, on OP's comment his name has a background :)

Comment: If that's the case, then we're back to my first comment: there's absolutely no good reason for CW posts to not count towards post bans.

Comment: @yannis Proof: [The Many Memes of Meta](/questions/19478). Scroll down and *TheTXI* has a few comments.

Comment: WHile somewhat orthogonal to your question - it seems to get harder to get a post ban as you accrue reputation, and its probably harder to get post banned on main meta.  So, even with the oddball nature of the sandbox (and no one's going to get mad if you *replace* your post with another), its unlikely you will get question banned in this specific scenario

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Community Wiki setting should never be used to accept a question which otherwise would *not* be allowed. In that vein, marking a post as Community Wiki has absolutely *no* bearing on whether the post is considered low quality or not.
∴
**The Community Wiki setting is *not* part of the post-ban equation.**

Comment: While it's reasonable for community wiki posts, I don't think posts in [the sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) should count towards a post ban.

Comment: Agree with @StevemCascellaro . As long as an answer in sandbox is not flagged as S or ROA (red flag).