# How can a moderator prevent their answer from being automatically converted to a comment on meta site?

Tags: support, comments, moderation, convert-to-comment

As discussed in this [meta thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98950/254520), I had some difficulty posting a valid answer to an [undelete request](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/q/431/1511) on the open data meta site.

My question is, as a mod of the site, and the fact that it is the meta site, what is the correct answer in this case? Or should I just do what I did, which was type in filler text until the answer was less "trivial"?

---

**edit**: question was self-deleted by user

[image]

Comment: Site mod is still a user, and while having all the privileges, most site rules still apply for them. No magic tool/button to avoid converting trivial answers to comment, even for mods/devs/CM.

Comment: Couldn't you add a bit more of an explanation as to why it was deleted (Roomba I guess?) so it might be useful to any new users that wonder why it might have been deleted? Also just a full sentence like "I've just undeleted this question now" would get you a fair part of the way there.

Comment: As a mod, you should know that "typing in filler text" is not the right approach. If it's not long enough to be a good answer, then it's not a good answer.

Comment: Since you're a moderator, you could add a *status-completed* tag instead.

Comment: @PeterJ it was deleted by the user

Comment: @AnneDaunted thanks, I've done that since reading your comment

Comment: @philshem that's odd, I always thought if you deleted your own post you could also undelete it as well? I guess they just might not have known that though.

Comment: @PeterJ maybe they could have, although it was easier to just do it myself

Answer (score 7):

Usually answers consisting of one word fit better as comments, no matter who the author is.

On meta sites, when moderator writes answer about completing a request it might be bit different, but still, adding some context is easy and usually trivial.

For example in that specific case, you can add context about why it was deleted in the first place. And if you're in a hurry it's also fine, no need in answer at all, just have it as comment, since it's not even a feature request.

Comment: in this case, the user had deleted the question themselves

Comment: I guess I didn't realize that since it wasn't a feature request, it doesn't need an answer to be marked as closed. I've since added the "status completed tag"

Comment: @philshem Then they can undelete their own question without any mod intervention. Perhaps you should mention that in the answer (ideally with some reference pointing out where the "undelete" button is located). However, if it was Roomba deleted, mod undeletion is indeed necessary.

Comment: thanks, I've edited my answer on that post